# Rails foundation 5 alerts won't fade out

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use Zurb foundation 5 alerts in my rails 4 application.
The [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html) mentions adding javascript to automatically fade out alert boxes through either data-options or making changes to the javascript directly.

Unfortunately I can't get either solution to work. No errors occur. I've checked the  and it does contain all three components needed (jquery.js, foundation.js and foundation.alerts.js)

I now there are some issues with version 5.1.1.0 of the foundation-rails gem, hence I've used version 5.0.3.1 as suggested [here](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_layout#zurb-foundation-50).

I'm not sure if it's something I'm missing or if it's a regular bug.
I'm using rails 4.0.3

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

It turns out that the 'fadeOut' works as documentet - but it's only when clicking the 'X' on the alert (manually closing). I'm looking for a way to **automatically** remove the alert after x number of seconds.

The documentation mentions the ability to tap into the events by using .on on the open.fndtn.alert-box and close.fndtn.alert-box. But I can't get the examples to work (those provided at the very bottom of the documention page.

Comment: does your app have foundation.alert.js on

Comment: As i wrote it has all three components needed; jquery.js, foundation.js and foundation.alerts.js

Comment: I've avoided the issue by setting a timeout if the alert is present

`if ($('.alert-box').length >= 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.alert-box .close').click();
        }, 5000);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at 
[Example](https://github.com/Kolyada/census)
- That has foundation 5 and working alerts

I usually use tooltips to check if JS works correctly.

Remeber to load foundation at the end of page's body:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation()
</script>
```

And puts files to load by "//= require_tree .":

```
/app/assets/javascripts/foundation.min.js 
/app/assets/javascripts/modernizr.js
```

Comment: Still can't get it working. As far for the example, it uses foundation-rails 4.3.2 unfortunately. https://github.com/Kolyada/census/blob/master/Gemfile.lock#L114